# asp.net mvc - tempdata values not available in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, tempdata

In the controller, I'm setting `TempData` values in the controller like this:

```
TempData["LinkControllerName"] = "Foos";
TempData["LinkActionName"] = "View";
```

When I try to consume them in the View, I find they're always null. I can use the debugger and see them being set, and then see that in the View they're null. I'm mystified.

The controller action is in fact a child action, and the View is being rendered via a call to `PartialView()` in the parent controller. There's no redirection taking place. Can anyone suggest what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not directly answer the question, but you hould use `ViewData` or `ViewBag` for passing extra values to the view from the Controller.

Comment: Actually, you've **sort of** answered my question. I found that I was using `TempData` in the controller, and `ViewData` in the View. :(